# My CSS rules are not getting applied when using chrome.tabs.insertCSS even when host page does not have any CSS applied

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For a chrome extension, I am trying to apply a set of CSS rules on some elements injected through a script. I tried separately running the injected html, explicitly linking the CSS file and it works in that case but nothing sort of works this way. Following is the code

Snippet from my manifest.json:

```
    "background": {
    "scripts": [ "Scripts/Background/background.js" ]
},


"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png"
    //"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "bookmarks",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "activeTab"

],

"web_accessible_resources": [
    "HTML/popup.html", "Scripts/External/jquery-2.1.3.min.js", "Scripts/Injected/loadExtUI.js", "Style/extUI.css"
]
```

My Background script:

```
// Supposed to be Called when the user clicks on the browser action icon.
function loadExt() {
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, { file: "Style/extUI.css" }, function () {
   alert("Inserted CSS") //This alert works
});
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "Scripts/External/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" }, function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "Scripts/Injected/loadExtUI.js"          });
 });
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(loadExt);
```

Scripts/Injected/loadExtUI.js:

```
var popup_root = document.getElementById('chimp_ext_container');
if (popup_root == null) {
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL("HTML/popup.html"), function (data) {
    //$(data).appendTo('body');
    // Or if you're using jQuery 1.8+:

    $($.parseHTML(data)).appendTo('body');
});
} else {
  document.body.removeChild(popup_root);
}
```

Style/extUI.css

```
#chimp_ext_container {
max-width: 420px !important;
overflow-x: hidden !important;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
font-size: 12px !important;
margin:1px !important;
padding:10px !important;
border: 1px groove !important;
border-radius: 5px !important;

background-color:aqua;

position: absolute !important;
top:10px !important;
float:right !important;
}
```

And finally, here is the HTML/pop

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chimpu</title>  
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="chimp_ext_container">
      <h1>Chimpu mera doshtttt!</h1>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The test page where I am running this is my own page which just has a

element with no other CSS applied so I am sure, nothing is interfering with my CSS file.

---

While debugging this, I observed that css styles applied to `<p>` gets properly seen but not to `<div>`!

Comment: Your code runs well on my end. I can see the text "Chimpu mera doshtttt!" with color of "aqua" and the appropriate size. Could you test it again by reloading the test page?

Comment: I tried refreshing page, reloading the extension but nothing helps. Surprising that it runs for you!

Comment: Is "your own page" by any chance on `file://` scheme?

Comment: Nope. Its on localhost